# Speed up all sprites in the game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

### Explanation

I'm trying to speed up my game when touching the screen (and decreasing its speeds when touching again). I kinda made it work, but not fully.

When touching the screen, all actions are removed and ran again (so it can read the new `gameSpeed`). But the sprites that were already spawned, won't be applied to the new action, so it still runs by the last `gameSpeed`. Is there any way to make all the sprites be speeded up?

### Code

This is the test code I made (you can download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/znbja8k5otaz2tu/AABTFVP45jWaDGCpefrvLq0pa?dl=0)):

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    // MARK: - Declare
    lazy var frameHeight : CGFloat = CGFloat(self.frame.height)

    var ball = SKSpriteNode()

    var speeded = Bool()
    var gameSpeed = CGFloat(1)

    // MARK: - Setup
    func setupBall(){

        ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
        ball.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height)
    }

    // MARK: - Action
    func actionsBall(){

        // Spawn ball
        self.setupBall()
        self.addChild(self.ball)

        // Move down and remove when go off screen
        let duration = (NSTimeInterval((0.003 / gameSpeed) * frameHeight))
        let moveBall = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -frameHeight, duration: duration)
        let removeBall = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        self.ball.runAction(SKAction.sequence([moveBall, removeBall]))
    }

    // MARK: - First Event
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

      // Start spawning, moving and removing
      runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration((0.00075 / Double(gameSpeed)) * Double(frameHeight)), SKAction.runBlock(self.actionsBall)])))
    }

    // MARK: - Touch
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        if speeded == false{

            speeded = true

            gameSpeed = 2

            removeAllActions()
            runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration((0.00075 / Double(gameSpeed)) * Double(frameHeight)), SKAction.runBlock(self.actionsBall)])))
        }
        else if speeded == true{

            speeded = false

            gameSpeed = 1

            removeAllActions()
            runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration((0.00075 / Double(gameSpeed)) * Double(frameHeight)), SKAction.runBlock(self.actionsBall)])))
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Update
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: have you tried maybe changing the `speed` value of the underlying physics world? Not sure if that affects actions.

Comment: yes, I tried to set `physicsWorld.speed = 2.0` and then back to `1.0`, but nothing happens =(

Comment: Try self.ball.speed = 2 to speed up a node (and its descendants) or self.speed = 2 for all nodes

Comment: Speeding up all nodes worked just perfect for my use, but I tried to speed up only a node and, as you said, its descendants, but only the last spawned node was speeded up.

Comment: By the way, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In the `didMove` method of your SKScene class, add the following:

```
physicsWorld.speed = CGFloat(2.0)
```

Most likely you simply didn't pass it as a `CGFloat` or it was not included in the proper method.